# Covering business cards?

Tags: adhesives, cardboard

I have a number of misprinted business cards and I plan on using them to test a card game.

I will be gluing prints(Normal low grade printer paper) to the cards, but I am worried the business cards will show through the thin paper.

Is there a way I can 'white over' the print to make sure nothing shows through the paper glued to the top?

Comment: Is cost an issue here? The total cost of the materials (not to mention the time involved) to *cover* the cards will almost certainly exceed what it would cost to buy new, blank card stock. You can buy pre-cut blank card stock, but a ream of 8-1/2 x 11" 65lb card stock cut at your local office supply shop should come to about US$0.006 each.

Answer (score 6):

You can paint (spray paint if you want to be quick) all cards before gluing the paper. Black spray paint will make everything even and often only needs one coat, white spray paint often needs 2-3 coats.

Comment: I think this will be the fastest way. Lay them all down on some news paper and spray paint. Then you can do the same with back side when the front side is dry. If you use spray glue, the gluing could be just as quick!